# Change a process' variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, communication, interprocess

I have a python program that periodically does some jobs according to that value of a given global variable "a". 
How can another python program change the value of "a" to (let's say) 20?

```py
a = 10
def run_program():
    global a
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(a)
```

I tried with OS signals, but a signal (e.g. USR1) can't pass variables

Any helps?

Comment: You can use an environment variable modify it in the first program and read it in the second one.

Comment: You taggerd [tag:interprocess] but your code does not show any attempt. Did you try anything from [https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ipc.html](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ipc.html) ? If so , share it. Asking us to code for you is out of scope (too broad, offtopic) of this sites purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an environment variable, modify it in the first program and use it the second one:

#### Program one:

```
import os
# Set environment variables
os.environ['YOUR_VARIABLE'] = 10
```

#### Program two:

```
import os
def run_program():
    a = os.environ.get('YOUR_VARIABLE')
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(a)
```

Notice also, that using this idea you avoid using a global variable.

Comment: I suppose that os.environ.get() is read inside the loop :-) Doing this, the variable is not affected by "Program one" :-/

Comment: @Leo I don't understand the problem, you want to read the variable inside the loop ? , you can do that.